# sprintf in C, loop never ends

Tags: c, printf

I am having a problem with loop, I don't know why but loop never ends.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int j;
    char s[2];
    for(j=1;j<=3;j++)
    {
        sprintf(s,"s%d",j);
        printf("%s", s);
    }
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

I think loop should show s1s2s3 in console.

Comment: Brilliant example of a question. SSCCE, expected outcome, actual outcome. Nothing more nothing less.

Comment: [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`char s[2];` should be `char s[3];`, or else you will get a buffer overflow.

---

[Abhineet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20518364/1508519) explains why the change is necessary. However, in order to corroborate his answer, here is the relevant section from the standard.

> 7.19.6.6
>
> The sprintf function is equivalent to fprintf, except that the output
>   is written into an array (speciﬁed by the argument s) rather than to a
>   stream. **A null character is written at the end of the characters
>   written**; it is not counted as part of the returned value. If copying
>   takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation,](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

> The size of the buffer should be large enough to contain the entire resulting string.

You are already pushing two chars to `s`, so, there is not enough space for appending `\0`. This will cause **undefined behavior**. The solution is to provide one extra char memory to append `\0`.

`char s[2];` to `char s[3];`

*I know I have replied pretty late but couldn't stop myself from explaining the OP, "why he has to use s[3] instead of s[2] ?"*